# Reading XML from Oracle DB as <column1>column2<column1> for each row

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

Table MESSAGE

> ```
>     ID PARAM_NAME PARAM_VALUE
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>      1 from       blah@example.org          
>      2 to         pew@example.org           
>      3 customer   John Doe                  
>      4 order      100500                    
>      5 status     yes
> ```

Result is simple xml string

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <data>
>     <from>blah@example.org</from>
>     <to>pew@example.org</to>
>     <customer>John Doe</customer>
>     <order>100500</order>
>     <status>yes</status>
> </data>
> ```

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(m.param_name, m.param_value) AS data 
FROM message m;
```

Does not work.

Comment: Do you have access to xmlgen package?

Comment: @RobertoNavarro: yes i have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because name of XML element is identifier you need to use `evalname` function:

```
with test_data as (
  select 1 id, 'from'     param_name, 'blah@example.org' param_value from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'to'       param_name, 'pew@example.org'  param_value from dual union all
  select 3 id, 'customer' param_name, 'John Doe'         param_value from dual union all
  select 4 id, 'order'    param_name, '100500'           param_value from dual union all
  select 5 id, 'status'   param_name, 'yes'              param_value from dual   
)
select 
  xmlelement("data", 
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement( evalname(param_name), param_value)
    )
  )
from test_data
order by id
```